# SAS macro if exists

Tags: if-statement, sas, macros, exists

If the dataset dataset_1&x._&y. exists, I want to get data from it, but if it doesn't exist i want to get data from dataset_2.

I have tried the following macro but it doesn't work:

```
%macro test(x,y);
    %if %sysfunc(exist(dataset_1_&x._&y.)) %then %do;
        data final_data;
        set dataset_1_&x,_&y.;
        run;
    %end;
    %else %do;
        data final_data;
        set dataset_2;
        run;
    %end;
%mend;
```

Comment: What are variables x and y? Your macro doesn't seem to use them at all. And what exactly do you want to achieve with this macro?

Comment: They are prompts that are specified earlier in the program, so y for example is set to 2020. And the dataset i want to check if exists is named dataset_1_&x._&y.

Comment: "set dataset_1_&x,_&y.;" Is this copied from your code? Because it should be "&x._&y.;"

Comment: You have an underscore in the data set in your code but not in the question. dataset_1&x._&y (question) is not the same as dataset_1_&x,_&y (code). Otherwise the code looks correct. If it doesn't work, show how you call the macro and the log from the code that doesn't work.

Comment: What means "it does'nt work" ? Is there an error message or are there unexpected results? Did you add an "options mprint symbolgen mlogic;" to your code? This will show you more information on your macro variables and logic. Or could you solve your problem by correcting the  "_&x,_&y." to "_&x._&y." as Negdo already mentioned. In other words, you have a comma instead of a point after &x in your code.

Comment: Have you _called_ the macro? The code above on its own does nothing but compile a macro for use later. To call it you must run `%test(value_x,value_y)` where `value_x` and `value_y` are inputs you specify, For example `%test(2002,01)` would look for a dataset called `dataset_1_2002_01`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this - no need to define a macro:

```
%let exist=%sysfunc(exist(work.dataset_1&x._&y.));
%let inds=%sysfunc(ifc(&exist=1,work.dataset_1&x._&y.,work.dataset_2));
data work.final_data;
  set &inds;
run;
```

If you did want a macro to see if a dataset (or view) exists, you could use this one: https://core.sasjs.io/mf__existds_8sas.html